How can I ensure efficient partition pruning when using dates from subqueries?
I use a table with a section based on date. The primary key index is built on the id and open_date.
If I use the date from the subquery, the planner will search through all partitions.
> EXPLAIN analyze SELECT * 
FROM calendar wc, tab t 
WHERE t.open_date =wc.wrk_day  
 AND wc.on_date ='2024-10-30'
 
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Hash JOIN  (cost=2.38..9602.67 ROWS=1099 width=85) (actual TIME=85.080..89.473 ROWS=41 loops=1)                                                  |
  Hash Cond: (t.open_date = wc.wrk_day)                                                                                                |
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..8758.21 ROWS=316133 width=69) (actual TIME=0.590..54.404 ROWS=315957 loops=1)                                          |
        ->  Seq Scan ON t_2024_02_01 t_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 ROWS=1 width=596) (actual TIME=0.060..0.061 ROWS=0 loops=1)           |
        ->  Seq Scan ON t_2024_02_02 t_2  (cost=0.00..0.00 ROWS=1 width=596) (actual TIME=0.012..0.012 ROWS=0 loops=1)           |
        ->  Seq Scan ON t_2024_02_03 t_3  (cost=0.00..0.00 ROWS=1 width=596) (actual TIME=0.008..0.008 ROWS=0 loops=1)           |
        ->  Seq Scan ON t_2024_02_04 t_4  (cost=0.00..0.00 ROWS=1 width=596) (actual TIME=0.007..0.007 ROWS=0 loops=1)           |
...
...
->  Hash  (cost=2.37..2.37 ROWS=1 width=16) (actual TIME=0.021..0.021 ROWS=1 loops=1)                                                         |
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                            |
        ->  INDEX Scan USING calendar_pkey ON calendar wc  (cost=0.15..2.37 ROWS=1 width=16) (actual TIME=0.008..0.009 ROWS=1 loops=1)|
              INDEX Cond: (on_date = '2024-10-30'::DATE)

IIf I input the date "October 30, 2024", the planner will filter out relevant partitions based on that date.
EXPLAIN analyze 
SELECT * 
FROM calendar wc, tab t 
WHERE t.open_date=wc.wrk_day  
 AND wc.on_date ='2024-10-30' AND t.open_date>='2024-10-29' AND t.open_date<'2024-11-01'
 
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Hash JOIN  (cost=2.38..33.53 ROWS=3 width=85) (actual TIME=0.037..0.320 ROWS=41 loops=1)                                                        |
  Hash Cond: (t.open_date = wc.wrk_day)                                                                                               |
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..28.90 ROWS=845 width=69) (actual TIME=0.012..0.225 ROWS=845 loops=1)                                                  |
        ->  Seq Scan ON t_2024_10_29 t_1  (cost=0.00..1.61 ROWS=41 width=69) (actual TIME=0.011..0.016 ROWS=41 loops=1)         |
              FILTER: ((open_date >= '2024-10-29'::DATE) AND (open_date < '2024-11-01'::DATE))                                            |
        ->  Seq Scan ON t_2024_10_30 t_2  (cost=0.00..1.87 ROWS=58 width=69) (actual TIME=0.005..0.011 ROWS=58 loops=1)         |
              FILTER: ((open_date >= '2024-10-29'::DATE) AND (open_date < '2024-11-01'::DATE))                                            |
        ->  Seq Scan ON t_2024_10_31 t_3  (cost=0.00..21.19 ROWS=746 width=69) (actual TIME=0.006..0.135 ROWS=746 loops=1)      |
              FILTER: ((open_date >= '2024-10-29'::DATE) AND (open_date < '2024-11-01'::DATE))                                            |
  ->  Hash  (cost=2.37..2.37 ROWS=1 width=16) (actual TIME=0.015..0.016 ROWS=1 loops=1)                                                         |
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                            |
        ->  INDEX Scan USING calendar_pkey ON calendar wc  (cost=0.15..2.37 ROWS=1 width=16) (actual TIME=0.012..0.013 ROWS=1 loops=1)|
              INDEX Cond: (on_date = '2024-10-30'::DATE)                                                                                        |
Planning TIME: 0.408 ms                                                                                                                         |
Execution TIME: 0.356 ms                                                                                                                        |
 
15 ROW(s) fetched.

I am looking for a way to use the date from a subquery and apply a filter.
DDL tab
CREATE TABLE usr.tab (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    open_date date NOT NULL,
    system_date timestamp NULL,
    amount numeric(19, 2) NULL
    CONSTRAINT tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, open_date)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (open_date);
CREATE INDEX tab_on_banking_date ON ONLY usr.tab USING btree (open_date);

CREATE TABLE usr.tab_2024_02 PARTITION OF usr.tab FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-02-01') TO ('2024-03-01')
PARTITION BY RANGE (open_date);
CREATE TABLE tab_2024_02_01 PARTITION OF tab_2024_02  FOR VALUES FROM ('2024-02-01') TO ('2024-02-02');

query with filter, it doesn't help
explain analyze 
    select
    wc.prev_work_day d_f_w 
    from work_calendar wc 
    left join account_document ad on ad.banking_date = wc.prev_work_day
    where wc.on_date = '2024-10-30' 

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Hash Right Join  (cost=2.38..7957.26 rows=1099 width=4) (actual time=71.377..75.512 rows=41 loops=1)                                                                                                      |
  Hash Cond: (ad.banking_date = wc.prev_work_day)                                                                                                                                                         |
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..7112.81 rows=316133 width=4) (actual time=0.540..54.097 rows=315957 loops=1)                                                                                                    |
        ->  Seq Scan on account_document_2024_02_01 ad_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                      |
        ->  Seq Scan on account_document_2024_02_02 ad_2  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                      |
        ->  Seq Scan on account_document_2024_02_03 ad_3  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                      |
        
etc...



Nothing's wrong with date. What's the question though? Why the databases scans all partitions?  If you don't limit the search to a partition then yes, the database has to search all partitions for matches. That's similar to asking a librarian for Chapter 7 without specifying the book. They'll have to search all books. To search only specific partitions you have to specify a filter on the partition column

This, really old article from more than 15 years ago, is worth reading: Bad Habits to Kick: Old-style JOINs

@PanagiotisKanavos Why is the date from wc.wrk_day ('2024-10-29') not supplied to the filter t.open_date='2024-10-29'? Does the order in which the request is executed affect wc.wrk_day? First we calculate wc.wrk_day, then we use this date in t.open_date?

You don't filter open_date anywhere, there's nothing to "supply". The 1980s-style JOIN  FROM calendar wc, tab t WHERE t.open_date =wc.wrk_day can match any date. The filter clause wc.on_date ='2024-10-30' doesn't involve the JOIN columns and so can't be used to eliminate partitions. That query can match rows whose open_date and wrk_day values are 2020-01-01 or 2025-01-01 as long as one of them has on_date ='2024-10-30'

@PanagiotisKanavos I don't understand... SELECT *  FROM calendar wc, tab t  WHERE **t.open_date =wc.wrk_day**  AND wc.on_date ='2024-10-30' How else can I use t.open_date' for example, to trigger the filter?

If I use
query explain analyze  select  * from  tab t where t.open_date = (select wc.wrk_day from calendar wc where wc.on_date='2024-10-30')
It doesn't help...
`QUERY PLAN
->  Seq Scan on tab_2024_02_01 t_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)
Filter: (banking_date = $0)
->  Seq Scan on tab_2024_02_02 t_2  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)
Filter: (banking_date = $0)`

When you are discussing this with code, please use [edit] so your query is readable!  Because you can properly format the SQL statement!

The way you do it in the second query. Actually specify a filter condition with a specific value in the WHERE clause. This way the database will know which partitions to look into. The current query is the equivalent of asking the librarian for two books that have the title Banana in Chapter 7. To actually prune partitions you'd have to also specify the section, eg Biology or Cooking, so the librarian can search in that catalog only

@PanagiotisKanavos Two dates are entered into the query input data: DateFrom and DateTo. Then I need to find out the previous business day from the DateFrom. The subquery returns the business day wrk_day as the date. Next, I need to insert this wrk_day into the main query and extract all the data for that date. I don't understand how it can be done otherwise.

I think you can use the same expression as you used when creating the partitioned table. Please share DDL of that table.

@Luuk added to the main topic

Yu can get the expressions from this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/221283/162995. this should result in something like: FROM ('2024-02-01') TO ('2024-03-01')) Yu should be able to extract the FROM and TO  that piece of text.....

@Luuk And how will it differ from (select wrk_day from calendar)? Partitioning takes by month. And I calculate range from wrk_day (f.e. 2024-10-29 - range 2024-10-01 and 2024-10-31). It's not specific value, but calculated. And as PanagiotisKanavos said, DB can match any date.

Sorry I cannot help you, I created table accoring to DDL, but on insert it is throwing an error, when executing insert into tab(id,open_date) values (1,'2024-02-02'::DATE); is answer with ERROR: no partition of relation "tab_2024_02" found for row   Detail: Partition key of the failing row contains (open_date) = (2024-02-02)  (see: DBFIDDLE)

@Luuk sorry, I forgot to mention another one partition. I've added it to the main topic.

@Luuk
I've repeated my situation
dbfiddle

I found another solution, to use an immutable function.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
work_day(DATE) RETURNS DATE AS $$
SELECT wc.prev_work_day FROM calendar wc WHERE wc.on_date= ($1)::DATE;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

EXPLAIN analyze
SELECT  *
FROM calendar wc 
LEFT JOIN tab t ON t.open_date=work_day('2024-10-30')
WHERE wc.on_date = '2024-10-30' 

QUERY PLAN           
                                                                                                                           
LIMIT  (cost=0.15..4.29 ROWS=41 width=85) (actual TIME=0.018..0.041 ROWS=41 loops=1)                                                             
->  Nested Loop LEFT JOIN  (cost=0.15..4.29 ROWS=41 width=85) (actual TIME=0.016..0.035 ROWS=41 loops=1)                                      |
    ->  INDEX Scan USING calendar_pkey ON calendar wc  (cost=0.15..2.37 ROWS=1 width=16) (actual TIME=0.005..0.006 ROWS=1 loops=1)|
          INDEX Cond: (on_date = '2024-10-30'::DATE)                                                                                        |
    ->  Seq Scan ON tab_2024_10_29 t  (cost=0.00..1.51 ROWS=41 width=69) (actual TIME=0.009..0.017 ROWS=41 loops=1)           |
          FILTER: (open_date = '2024-10-29'::DATE)                                                                                       |
 Planning TIME: 0.325 ms                                                                                                                         |
 Execution TIME: 0.070 ms                                                                                                                        |

 8 ROW(s) fetched.

Cost from
Hash Right Join  (cost=2.38..9602.70 rows=1099 width=85) (actual time=82.200..86.531 rows=41 loops=1)

To
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..4.29 rows=41 width=85) (actual time=0.017..0.036 rows=41 loops=1)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I changed some line in your last DBFIDDLE, and did keep the line before change as comment.
explain analyze
select * from cal
left join tab on tab.open_date=cal.prev_work_day
-- where cal.on_date = '2024-02-02'
where cal.on_date = '2024-02-03'
;

plan:



QUERY PLAN




Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.15..138.00 rows=32 width=52) (actual time=0.020..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)


->  Index Scan using work_calendar_pkey on cal  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)


Index Cond: (on_date = '2024-02-03'::date)


->  Append  (cost=0.00..129.53 rows=30 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)


->  Seq Scan on tab_2024_02_01 tab_1  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36) (never executed)


Filter: (open_date = cal.prev_work_day)


->  Seq Scan on tab_2024_02_02 tab_2  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)


Filter: (open_date = cal.prev_work_day)


->  Seq Scan on tab_2024_02_03 tab_3  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36) (never executed)


Filter: (open_date = cal.prev_work_day)


->  Seq Scan on tab_2024_03_01 tab_4  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36) (never executed)


Filter: (open_date = cal.prev_work_day)


->  Seq Scan on tab_2024_03_02 tab_5  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36) (never executed)


Filter: (open_date = cal.prev_work_day)


Planning Time: 0.192 ms


Execution Time: 0.078 ms



Please do note the never executed
PostgreSQL will only search tab_2024_02_02 because the optimizer knows that some data might be found in that partition.
(Better described answers might be when asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com)
